# Running a Symfony database migration script at Docker container startup

Tags: docker, symfony, docker-compose, database-migration, dockerfile

Hope that question title isn't too confusing.

Basically I have a Symfony 3 application build upon Docker.

I would like to have the DB migrations for the app run at Docker startup. Basically so that I can have the app up and running with fixture data by just running 'docker-compose up'.

However what if all of your containers are coming from images?

My app will run with the following docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: symfony_nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes_from:
      - php
    volumes:
      - ./etc/build/dev/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./var/logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx

  php:
    image: letsbonus/php-dev:7.0
    container_name: symfony_php
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - "2222:22"
    working_dir: /app

  redis:
    image: redis:3.0.7-alpine
    container_name: symfony_redis

  elk:
    image: willdurand/elk
    container_name: symfony_elk
    ports:
        - "81:80"
    volumes:
        - ./etc/build/dev/elk/logstash:/etc/logstash
        - ./etc/build/dev/elk/logstash/patterns:/opt/logstash/patterns
    volumes_from:
        - php

  database:
    container_name: symfony_mysql
    image: mysql
    command: --general-log=/var/log/mysql/general.log
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=symfony
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

But would then require me to manually run the migrations.

Since I couldn't figure out how to do it I thought I would add another container definition to docker-compose.yml

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile.migrations
volumes_from:
  - php
links:
  - database
  - php
depends_on:
  - database
  - php
```

However the custom dockerfile started to grow arms and legs as you can see below.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y sudo
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
RUN apt-get install -y php7.0 php-xml php7.0-mysql
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server-core-5.7 mysql-client-5.7

WORKDIR /app
COPY opt/deployment/development/run.sh /usr/bin
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/run.sh" ]
```

This all seems a bit much just to run a shell script, which makes me assume I am missing something and doing it wrong.

Any thoughts on the correct/best way to achieve this?